# How can I run individual tests with Test::Class::Load?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

After having accumulated enough tests that running them all takes some real time, I looked at the [`Test::Class::Load` doc](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Test-Class/lib/Test/Class/Load.pm) to find a tip for running individual test classes.  It provides a manner to do this, but I must be missing something, because I can't make it work.  Here's what I have:

My test directory:

```
drewfus:~/sandbox$ ls t/
lib/  perlcriticrc  PerlCritic.t  Unit.t
```

`t/Unit.t` consists of the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::Class;
use Test::More 'no_plan';
use Test::Class::Load 't/lib';
```

Per the suggestion in the [`Test::Class::Load` doc](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Test-Class/lib/Test/Class/Load.pm#CUSTOMIZING_TEST_RUNS), I have a base class for each of my test classes to inherit from, `SG::TestBase` that lives at `t/lib/SG/TestBase.pm`:

```
package SG::TestBase;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Test::Class';

INIT { Test::Class->runtests }

1;
```

And finally, here is an example test class, `SG::UtilsTest` at `t/lib/SG/UtilsTest.pm`:

```
package SG::UtilsTest;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'SG::TestBase';

BEGIN { use_ok('SG::Utils') };
<etc>
```

Everything is still peachy if I want to run all of the tests with `Build test` or `prove`, but trying to run an individual test doesn't work:

```
drewfus:~/sandbox$  prove -lv SG::UtilsTest
Cannot determine source for SG::UtilsTest at /usr/share/perl/5.10/App/Prove.pm line 496
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations on spotting the mistake in the documentation :-)

The final argument should be the path to the test class - not the package name. You'll also need to add the path to the test class libraries so prove can find them Doing:

```
  prove -lv -It/lib t/lib/SG/UtilsTest.pm
```

should work.

Comment: This works, but seven years later the documentation still has the same error.